# appengine disable app versions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps

I have a test app on app engine.

I incremented its version and deployed again

now If I modify some data in one version, it is written on datastore that 2nd version uses (because version point to same store)

how can I disable the version, without deleting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one datastore that's common to all versions.  It's not like each version has its own datastore.

You can set a default version, but you can't prevent anyone from directly forcing a version by going to http://version.appid.appspot.com

Answer (score 2):

you could use namespaces to separate the data between versions.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/overview